# How to select only hidden folder from String[]?

Tags: c#

I want to know how to get only hidden folder from String[]. Actually I have one string array and there show some files. There have normal and hidden files also but I want to try select only hidden folder from this array. So anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Create `FileInfo` object for each file and the use its `Directory` property to get a `DirectoryInfo` instance on which you can check the `Attributes` property that will tell you if the directory is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether a directory is hidden by checking `Attributes` property of the `DirectoryInfo` class:

```
var info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var hidden = info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden
```

The same code would work for testing whether a file is hidden, but you'd use `FileInfo` instead of `DirectoryInfo`. It is not clear what your array contains and what do you want to get, but generally, you could use LINQ to implement filtering. The following returns a new collection containing only hidden directories:

```
var hiddenDirectories = allDirectories.Where(path => {
  var info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
  var hidden = (info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden
  return hidden; });
```

You should be able to adapt this to your needs (depending on what files/directories you want to get as the result).

Comment: Throw one exception against info. exception is Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Attributes'