# how to get hidden folder from string array

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select only hidden folder from String[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935293/how-to-select-only-hidden-folder-from-string)

```
folderBrowserDialog1.Reset();
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath != "")
{
  sourcetxt.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
  string[] path = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
}
```

i am write this code.i have get all folder with hidden folder of this array name of path .But i trying to get only hidden folder of this array (array name path).please please solve this problem any one.

Thankig You.

Comment: You already asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935293/how-to-select-only-hidden-folder-from-string/2935311. Perhaps you could clarify your original question instead of asking the same thing again?

Answer (score 1):

```
...
string[] path = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
   .EnumerateDirectories()
   .Where(x=>x.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden)
   .Select(x=>x.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: Just a small mistake in the filter : `x => (x.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden`

Comment: Or better, since you're using .NET 4 : `x => x.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)`